# What decides tech-priest initiative?

Tags: warhammer-40k-mechanicus

For most of the game so far I have had my "paladin"-like enginseer going first or second in the turn order in respect to the units under my control. I liked it like that as it let me charge him as a vanguard initially and then heal others on their next turn.

Recently though, the game has been putting him dead last in the turn order and it has made the unit much more useless than they were originally. Only thing I can think of that has changed is that I got a 4th tech-priest (the enginseer is one of the 2 I started with). I don't see any indicator of an initiative stat

Is there something I can change to get them going first again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having further played the game, it would seem that there is only one real initiative factor. Outside of battles, some events with affect the initiative meter to swing either in your favor or that of the Necrons. If it is in favor of you, then **all** of your units go before the Necrons and vice versa.

However, if it is in neutral favor, it randomizes all turns. There does not seem to be any bias towards particular tech-priests. This also applies when one side does have the initiative boost, it just does it in a separated fashion rather than a jumble of everyone.

This randomized order seems to stick throughout a mission and only re-randomizes upon picking a new mission.

For instance, Tech-priest Marelius goes 2nd relative to all tech-priests during a mission to destroy a Necron artifact. All battles during this mission have him going 2nd. Upon selecting a new mission, even without any gear or skill changes, Marelius will go 6th,

Comment: Some Necron units have high initiative, allowing them to act twice in a turn.
Destroyer is one such example - in my battles Destroyers generally act as the first, or the second, unit in the round, and then once again as the last unit in the round.